# Is it possible to name the child processes of a ThreadPool in python3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

In java it's possible to set up the thread pool such that there is a thread factory that initialises the threads spawned by the pool. This factory then can set up the threads so that they have particular names or priorities. Here's an example I wrote some years ago:

```
    /** A custom implementation of ThreadFactory which names pool threads accordingly and
     *  allows setting priority of the created threads. Delivers non daemon threads.
     *  
     *  @param threadPriority - desired level or priority for created threads, if this value 
     *  is smaller than Thread.MIN_PRIORITY or greater than Thread.MAX_PRIORITY 
     *  a default value of Thread.NORM_PRIORITY is used. 
     * */
    protected class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        private final ThreadGroup group;
        private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
        private final String namePrefix;
        private final int DEF_PRIORITY = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY;
        private final int priority;

        FeverThreadFactory(int threadPriority) {
            SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
            group = (s != null)? s.getThreadGroup() : Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
            namePrefix = "worker-pool-thread-";

            boolean validPriority = threadPriority > Thread.MIN_PRIORITY && 
                                    threadPriority < Thread.MAX_PRIORITY;

            this.priority = validPriority ? threadPriority : DEF_PRIORITY;

        }

        public Thread  newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(group, r, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),0);

            if (t.isDaemon())
                t.setDaemon(false);

            t.setPriority(this.priority);     
            return t;
        }
    }
```

I have checked the ThreadPool and ThreadPoolExecutor from multiprocessing and concurrent.futures modules respectively but didn't see anything relevant. Is it possible to do something like that in Python3?